# How do I rigorously prove that a ball dropped straight down doesn't move sideways (with quadratic air resistance)?

Tags: calculus

Consider a 2D problem in which I drop a baseball straight down from some height. In this regime, one can show that the dominant contribution to the drag is a quadratic dependence directed opposite the velocity of the ball.

Translating the above into a mathematical form, we are interested in solving
$$m\ddot{\mathbf{r}} = m\mathbf{g} - cv^2\hat{\mathbf{v}}$$
where $c$ is a constant characteristic of the drag force for this situation. This decomposes in Cartesian coordinates into the coupled equations (choosing up as positive)
$$m\dot{v}_x = -c\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}v_x$$
$$m\dot{v}_y = -mg -c\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}v_y,$$
subject to the initial conditions $v_x(0) = v_y(0) = 0$.

Now I solved this by "arguing physically" that $v_x(0) = v_x(t) = 0$, so that the latter equation reduced to the tractable form
$$m\dot{v}_y = -mg -cv_y^2.$$
My question is about how one can prove this ($v_x(0) = v_x(t) = 0$) rigorously. Usually, in problems like this the relevant coordinate differential equations are decoupled so that we have an easy argument. Here, they are not, so I'm wondering if someone better versed in differential equations than I can explain what the rigorous argument would be here.

Comment: What's wrong with saying that when $v_x = 0$, then $\dot{v}_x = 0$, so $v_x$ always remains zero? That's just a statement about how calculus works.

Comment: @EE18 "Using the initial condition data" is the key point. In either case (drag or not) the initial conditions are completely independent of the differential equation you're solving. If you are comfortable saying that $v_x(0) = 0$ for the case with no drag, what stops you from doing this for the case with drag?

Comment: @knzhou I completely agree that this must be true, and can make a physicit's "Taylor series" argument that this should be true at $dt$, and so at $2dt$, and so at..., but I'm wondering if there's any way to just make this precise like a mathematician would.

Comment: Because in the former case I can show it explicitly by integrating the differential equation and using FTC, whereas here I can't integrate the given differential equation a priori. @d_b

Comment: A mathematician would say that the equation $\dot{v}_x = f(t) v_x$ for some $f$ satisfies the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs in some time interval, and $v_x(t) = 0$ is a solution to the equation that fits the boundary conditions, so it must be the unique solution. Uniqueness theorems are the general way the mathematician rigorizes the physicist's method of guessing solutions. But I don't think they really add much insight here.

Comment: @EE18 I see your issue now. I believe one can make an argument from the phase velocity vector field on the $(v_x, v_y)$ phase space. Along the line $v_x = 0$, this vector field only has a $v_y$ component, so phase curves beginning on the line have to remain along the line (since the phase velocity must be tangent to a phase curve).

Comment: I think this question might be better served at the [math.se]. The problem can be rewritten without reference to "velocity," "gravity," etc. For example, as: $\dot u = -u\sqrt{u^2+w^2}$, $\dot w = -\beta -w\sqrt{u^2+w^2}$, subject to $u(0)=w(0)=0$. The question is then: Why is $u(t)$ zero for all time?

Comment: @hft Is there a way to port questions over?

Comment: Do note that while the mathematical treatment of the question is interesting in its own right, there is also the experimental fact that, actually, we are neglecting the effects of, say, air turbulence. In reality, the actual motion will have a stochastic component that nudges the baseball in some Brownian motion spread around the mean of zero. You should also analyse the fact that $\dot v_x\propto-v_x$ is opposing any deviation, i.e. $v_x=0$ is not just a fixed point (line on phase space) but a stable and attractive one. Leads to chaos theory and dynamical analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differential equation is invariant under reflection $x \to -x$, therefore the reflection of any solution is a solution.  Since the initial condition is also invariant, and the solution is unique, the solution with this initial condition must be invariant under reflection as well, thus $x(t) = 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Consider a 2D problem in which I drop a baseball straight down from some height. In this regime, one can show that the dominant contribution to the drag is a quadratic dependence directed opposite the velocity of the ball.

> Translating the above into a mathematical form, we are interested in solving
> $$m\ddot{\mathbf{r}} = m\mathbf{g} - cv^2\hat{\mathbf{v}}$$

> ... My question is about how one can prove this ($v_x(0) = v_x(t) = 0$) rigorously.

It is my understanding that OP is not interested in "physical" arguments, but rather wants to understand how to solve this non-linear differential equation directly and "rigorously."

First, it is helpful to remove the dimensional units (velocity, acceleration, etc.) and consider the related problem:
$$
\dot u = -u\sqrt{u^2 + w^2}\tag{1}
$$
$$
\dot w = \beta - w\sqrt{u^2+w^2}\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
w(0)=u(0)=0\;.
$$

Note that the we expect "intuitively" that $u(t)=0$ for all time and that $w(t)\to -\sqrt{\beta}$ (which is analogous to the terminal velocity in this case).

The Equations (1) and (2) above are equivalent to the original problem after making the appropriate substitutions to get rid of the dimensionful constants.

---

Recall, that a first order differential equation with given boundary condition has a unique solution. Therefore, if we can *guess* the solution, we will have "rigorously" solved the equation.

Our guess at the solution is
$$
u(t)=0
$$
and
$$
w(t)=\sqrt{\beta}\frac{e^{\sqrt{\beta}t}-e^{-t\sqrt{\beta}}}{e^{\sqrt{\beta}t}+e^{-t\sqrt{\beta}}} = \sqrt{\beta}\tanh(\sqrt{\beta}t)\;.
$$

You can check that the above solution satisfies the differential equations and the boundary conditions and therefore it is the correct unique solution to the problem. And, therefore, the x velocity will never be non-zero, as was our original "intuitive" expectation.

---

To explain how I can up with my amazingly accurate "guess" for $w(t)$, consider the general differential equation:
$$
\frac{dw}{dt} = F(w)\;,
$$
which can be solved formally as:
$$
\int \frac{dw}{F(w)} = t + C\;,
$$
and, thankfully, in our case the $1/F(w)$ can be integrated analytically and results in an inverse hyperbolic tangent.

---

In terms of the original problem, the solution becomes:
$$
v_x(t) = 0
$$
and
$$
v_y(t) = -\sqrt{\frac{mg}{c}}\tanh(\sqrt{\frac{gc}{m}}t)
$$

Comment: Thanks as always for your help here @hft I’ve gone with the other answer just because it was completely unexpected, but I appreciate you codifying the guess-and-check method rigorously as an exercise in using uniqueness here.

Answer (score 0):

you don't habe analytical solution , but you can obtain  "numerical solution" , with a simple EULER integration method.

with
\begin{align*}
&\dot{\mathbf{y}}=\mathbf f(\mathbf y)\\
  &\mathbf y=\begin{bmatrix}
          v_x \\
          v_y \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \quad ,\mathbf f(y)=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} -c\sqrt {{v_{{x}}}^{2}+{v_{{y}}}^{2}}v_{{x}}
\\ -mg-c\sqrt {{v_{{x}}}^{2}+{v_{{y}}}^{2}}v_{{y}}
\end {array} \right]
\end{align*}

integration with EULER method

\begin{align*}
 &\mathbf y_{i+1}=\mathbf y_i+h\,\mathbf f(\mathbf y)\bigg|_{\mathbf y=\mathbf y_{i-1}}\quad, i=2\ldots n
\end{align*}

with the initial conditions
\begin{align*}
& \mathbf y_1=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
      \end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align*}

you obtain
\begin{align*}
 &\mathbf y_2=\begin{bmatrix}
          v_x \\
          v_y \\
        \end{bmatrix}_{t=h}=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\ -hmg\end {array}
 \right]        
        \end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 &\mathbf y_3=\begin{bmatrix}
          v_x \\
          v_y \\
        \end{bmatrix}_{t=2\,h}=
 \left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\ -2\,hmg+c{h}^{3}{m}^{2
}{g}^{2}\end {array} \right]\\
&\vdots\\
&\mathbf y_n=\begin{bmatrix}
          v_x \\
          v_y \\
        \end{bmatrix}_{t=n\,h}=
\begin{bmatrix}
          0 \\
          \ldots \\
        \end{bmatrix}        
        \end{align*}

thus $~ v_x(~t_n~)=0$